# Any reason not to change [tag:covid-19-virus] to [tag:covid-19], or merge these two in some other way?

Tags: discussion, tagging

This [question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6560/1810) posted by [Relaxed](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6669/relaxed) on the Travel Stack Exchange  also applies here:

> I was surprised to discover that the tag regarding the current pandemic is [covid-19-virus](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19-virus). As the blurb describing the tag correctly explains, “Covid-19” is not the name of the virus but the name of the disease. It's also shorter, unambiguous and, by now, well established (which might not have been the case a few months ago). Any reason not to change it to [covid-19](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19)?

Comment: The name of the virus itself is "SARS-CoV-2".  Having [tag:covid-19-virus] makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the questions here were tagged covid-19. I have edited the two that were not to match the others